# How to do binary search by table with known data order in specific fields SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm

I have a table with structure like this:

```
create table to_much_data
(
    id primary key clustered,
    dt datetime,
    data varbinary(400)
)
```

it didn't have an index by datetime, but i know that dt non-decreasing sequence.
I need to query data from this table with specific condition by date field like this:

```
select * 
from to_much_data
where dt between '20190220' and '20190221'
```

since no index for dt, i prefer to convert query to:

```
select * 
from to_much_data
where id between StartDateID and EndDateID
```

I believe that `StartDateID` and `EndDateID` could be found with log(N) or better complexity. But I didn't know any solution to do this.

Does any one know the way to do it?

**UPD**

It looks like no wide-known ready to use solution exists. If index creation is not possible some workarounds can be used:

- filtered index, but it can affect table performance and increase
  locks
- another table with mapping, but it needs to be manually updated (or through trigger or stored procedure) and it can affect performance and increase locks
- t-sql code with silly binary search but it looks like bicycle reinventing

despite this I believe that databases can be more effective and intuitive in some cases like this. I will be glad if some day we will be able to write:

```
select * 
from to_much_data with(sequence_order(id asc, dt asc))
where dt between '20190220' and '20190221'
```

Comment: What's stopping you from doing the obvious and *creating the index* on `dt`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just couldn't do it (

Comment: Do you REALLY want to make such an assumption? And do you REALLY understand the implications here about sequencing? But first, let's talk about your wording - because it implies something you might miss. "Non-decreasing" does not mean "increasing" - it implies duplicate values. Your choice of words - think carefully. Unless you are willing to make some significant assumptions about the number of rows inserted, the values they contain, how they are statistically spread out over time, your goal is impossible. Even with assumptions, your goal is very high risk.

Comment: @SMor yes non decreasing since date time could have several values can be the same. And if whole table have same dt in range so I need whole table, if thousand records well I need it, even without statistic it will fast and I don't see high risk here for my task. Do you know some solution?

Comment: you can't expect `log(N)` performance on `between` operation. Worst case is if all rows are applicable. So, it becomes `O(N)`.

Comment: @vivek_23, I said that 'StartDateID and EndDateID could be found with log(N)'. I don't care about worst cases, because it uselessly. I mean asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @gabba I also mean asymptotic complexity. I don't feel you can via SQL. Better  fetch all rows and do binary search programmatically.

Comment: @vivek_23, do you realy feel that load 100 billion records is a good idea?

Comment: @gabba You never said that before in your question and you also said that you could not do indexing.

Comment: @vivek_23, I named table to_much_data, so it hints that full scan and new index are big pain

Comment: This is an interesting problem from a theoretical perspective. The obvious solution uses a plain old sequential loop for the binary search, but a recursive CTE should be able to do it as well. As interesting as it is as theoretical problem, though, I'd never implement it in practice, since you're essentially reinventing the whole concept of indexing. You would end up with some pretty unreadable queries if you had to do this more than once. If you have the resources for an enormous table, you should have the resources for another index.

Comment: @gabba table names are not a strong hint to signify what issues you are facing. You will need to explicitly mention them. Also, is the current query that you showed under perfoming? It should perform good on average case since you said that `dt non-decreasing sequence`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert very happy to see that you understood what I meant. I know that it can be done with cte but hoped that ready to use solution existed. In case with frequently write and very rare read index is very expensive. It need to much space and time to rebuild

Comment: @vivek_23, full scan absolutely no good for this case

Comment: If it would be very rarely used, consider if you could make a filtered index (`INDEX .. ON too_much_data(dt) WHERE ID BETWEEN x AND y`) and/or maintain your own mapping table for this purpose. For example, when a new day rolls around, you could store the lowest ID then present in a separate table (this could be done with a trigger, a job, or as part of an ETL load step, depending on how your table gets data). While slightly clumsy to use, it would still be more intuitive than having to do a binary search on demand.

Comment: Another totally hacky solution would be to create a secondary table with say, everything ten-thousandths row.  Then you could query IDs from the secondary table that would encompass and envelop all the values you wanted from the main table.  (ie. a superset of the data you want.) You could then query the too_much_data table from the IDs you pull from the secondary table, (since that IS indexed) and then filter that result with the BETWEEN, which would now be operating on a much smaller subset of values.

Comment: If it's really that huge, have you considered partitioning the table by yyyyMM ?

Comment: @LukStorms, good idea! partitioning reduce scan volume, but any way whats better: scan month or by well known id range?

Comment: With partition it can mean that one also start to use the partition in the queries, together with your normal criteria.  The downside is the maintenance for new partitions.

Comment: @LukStorms, ok if the table was already partitioned it would be a little easier for me. But what to do now?

Comment: Not sure. I have a hunch that you aren't the database administrator, and try to get a solution that doesn't involve a db admin.  Maybe using an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views) could help, if adding an index to the table isn't an option.  But I think you should have a talk about best options with the database administrator(s).

Comment: @LukStorms, if we think about this task in terms of efficiency. What more efficient do giant indexing work and store enormous size of data or do a hundred pk look up several times a day?

Comment: Heh, just thought of a crazy idea.  If those records with datatimes are inserted sequential, and you're more intested in data of the current day? Then what if keep a table where you store the minimum id per Startdate.  Then for the next queries on "to_much_data" you could filter on id >= minid.

Comment: @LukStorms, yes it good idea. Jeroen Mostert advised somthing like this. But it need to maintenance some "index" data automatically by trigger or stored procedure or manualy. In case of automatic solutions this logic should be executed for each record

Comment: I don't think it should be for each record (which could be done via a trigger probably). But a job that runs once a day to add the minimum id for the current day to that other table.

Comment: @LukStorms, I don't believe that a job that will scan several million records are better than hundred pk look up

Comment: If there is a more or less predictable number of records per date then you may be able to derive the index range from that. Without high predictability it almost becomes as silly as a binary search in T-SQL though.

Comment: IMHO, any solution that doesn't involve adding an index to the table is pretty much re-inventing indexes in this way or another. I think that for a production table, it's best to simply add an index, even if it means adding more disk space or memory to the server (these are really cheap nowadays anyway).

Comment: You could create an indexed view with `WHERE (id % 100000 = 0)`  to get an index with a million rows rather than the whole 100 billion and then use that to get the min and max id boundaries. Obviously the boundaries won't be precise so you will still end up reading more rows than needed

Comment: @MartinSmith, This is a great idea. Will try it. Thanks

Comment: @ZoharPeled, You are right. But it very sad because we have easy to implement solution that can improve performance for that cases

Comment: @gabba Is ID an identity column (always ascending)?

Comment: Perhaps a Columnstore index may well help - look at the section "When does an analytics query benefit from rowgroup elimination for a full-table scan?" in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-query-performance?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 8):

You could just reproduce the binary search algorithm in TSQL or use a recursive CTE but this is still going to need greater than 70 seeks to get both ends and is tedious to do.

A possible middle ground might be to create an indexed view with at least every nth row. For example

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.to_much_data_Sample
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT id,
         dt
  FROM   dbo.to_much_data
  WHERE  id % 100000 = 0

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix
  ON dbo.to_much_data_Sample(dt, id);
```

you can then use (assuming `id` is an integer)

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20190220',
        @EndDate   DATETIME = '20190221';

DECLARE @StartDateID INT,
        @EndDateID   INT;

SELECT TOP 1 @StartDateID = id
FROM   dbo.to_much_data_Sample WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE  dt < @StartDate
ORDER  BY dt DESC;

SELECT TOP 1 @EndDateID = id
FROM   dbo.to_much_data_Sample WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE  dt > @EndDate
ORDER  BY dt ASC;

SELECT *
FROM   to_much_data
WHERE  id BETWEEN isnull(@StartDateID, -2147483648) AND isnull(@EndDateID, 2147483647)
       AND dt BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

[image]

The value of `n` will be a trade off between index size and number of additional rows read at runtime.

Comment: nice answer.  But what i hate about schema binding view is its limitation on DDL on the table.  Though it is noted you can change the view into non-schema binding then do the drop/alter column etc, it's a bit of pain of additional work.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't directly answering your question directly but I think it's worth adding this information anyway

It's worth considering whether you **really** know that the datetime's are "nondecreasing"

For example:

- What happens if someone sets the clock on the server (e.g. due to time drift)?
- If more than one server is generating the `datetime` values then their clocks probably wont' be *exactly* synchronised.
- If the dates are generated by one server can you be sure this be true for the lifetime of the application?

The chances are that, unless you've got a workaround to the above then the dates will not be non-decreasing with respect to id.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the ID on the Too_Much_Data table is an identity, this could be a solution for you:

```
CREATE TABLE MaxIdForDate (
        d DATE
    ,   id INT --match datatype of to_much_data's pk
)

CREATE INDEX IX_MaxIdForDate_d_id ON MaxIdForDate(d,id)
GO

--Nightly stored procedure does this
INSERT INTO MaxIdForDate(d,id)
    SELECT
            CONVERT(DATE,tmd.dt) AS d
        ,   MAX(tmd.id) AS id
    FROM to_much_data tmd
    WHERe tmd.id > (
        SELECT MAX(id)
        FROM MaxIdForDate mx
    )
    AND CONVERT(DATE,tmd.dt)<CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
    GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,tmd.dt)
GO

--New Query
    DECLARE @StartDate DATE='02/20/2019'
    DECLARE @EndDate DATE='02/21/2019'

    select tmd.* 
    from to_much_data tmd
    WHERE tmd.id > (SELECT id FROM MaxIdForDate WHERE d=DATEADD(DAY,-1,@StartDate))
    and tmd.id <= (SELECT id FROM MaxIdForDate WHERE d=@EndDate)
```

Comment: This solution will be appropriate for some one, but it still will scan many data each time and need to do Nightly proc

Comment: @gabba not sure what you mean by scanning many data. You are pulling back a huge number of rows and pulling back based on the primary key should be the fastest option.

Comment: We discussed this solution erly, if I have min max values by day I need to scan milions rows if I need a minutes

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that you can't create index on data column.

what is not clear is rest of the columns in table and its data type and how the real search will look like ?

Because it matter.

Whatever I have understood,it is not a candidate for `Filtered Index`,I mean date range are not good candidate for `Filtered Index`.

BTW, if you can think of filtered Index then Why not Create index on date columns ?

Range Search are not ideal for `Binary Search` either, especially in Sql server.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
SET NoCount on

declare @StartDateID int
declare @EndDateID int

select @StartDateID=min(id), @EndDateID=max(id)
from dbo.to_much_data
where dt between '20190220' and '20190221'

select id,dt,[data]
from to_much_data
where id >= @StartDateID and id <= @EndDateID
```

It may be good candidate for `Partition` but we need to know other details like 
how many rows are there ?

Data are populated from which source and how many rows can be inserted at one time ?

How frequently data are inserted/updated ?

Edit :

Sample data,

```
SET STATISTICS XML OFF
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE
    @i  INTEGER = 1,
    @s  FLOAT = RAND(20120104),
    @e  FLOAT = RAND();
    declare @jj datetime='2009-01-01'
WHILE @i <= 1000000
BEGIN
        if(@i=1000000 or @i=2000000)
        set @jj=dateadd(year,1,@jj)

    INSERT dbo.SomeDateTable
        (
        StartDate, 
        vdata
        )
    VALUES
        (
        DATEADD(DAY, @s * 365, @jj),
       cast(REPLICATE('A',500) as varbinary(500))
        )

    SELECT
        @s = RAND(),
        @e = RAND(),
        @i += 1
END
```

You can check the daterange distribution in my sample, and correct the date range and post back.

```
declare @SDate datetime='2009-07-11'
declare @EDate datetime='2012-12-30'
declare @Sid int
declare @Eid int

--select * from dbo.SomeDateTable
--where StartDate>=@SDate and StartDate<=@EDate

Above query give Table Scan  

select @Sid=min(id) ,@Eid=max(id) from dbo.SomeDateTable
where StartDate>=@SDate and StartDate<=@EDate
```

This query give 2 index scan but sub query cost is very less

```
select @Sid,@Eid
select id,StartDate,vdata from dbo.SomeDateTable
where id>=@Sid and id<=@Eid
```

This query is index seek

I am, quite sure about this in given condition

Comment: Thanks for paying attention. I have several millions inserts per day, insert batch size up to 1000 records.No updates

Comment: your query of Start/End ID will full scan a table

Comment: Have you tested it ? can you show actual plan ? how many data on avg can be between started and endid ?

Comment: Have you test your submission?

Comment: @gabba , Check my edited .can you once review your post since we have discuss lot of thing.?Thamks

Comment: Thanks, but my question about another thing and about another table structure )
Your solution do the same work with same db efforts. If you reread the question you will see that I look for ready to use solution that uses wide-known algorithm: binary search.

Comment: @gabba, my solution is somewhat same as Martin,yes `Indexed view` suggestion is quite ok. Also I clearly wrote that Binary Search in Range search is not feasible.